# Change value of only 1 cell based on criteria DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on a condition, I want to change the value of the first row on a certain column, so far this is what I have

```
despesas['recibos'] =''
for a in recibos['recibos']:
    if len(despesas.loc[(despesas['despesas']==a) & (despesas['recibos']==''), 'recibos'])>0:
        despesas.loc[(despesas['despesas']==a) & (despesas['recibos']==''), 
'recibos'].iloc[0] =a
```

So I want to change only the first value of the column *recibos* by the value on *a* where *(despesas['despesas']==a) & (despesas['recibos']=='')*

**Edit 1**

Example:

```
despesas['despesas'] = [11.95,  2.5,  1.2 ,  0.6 ,  2.66,  2.66,  3.  , 47.5 , 16.95,17.56]
recibos['recibos'] = [11.95,  1.2 ,  1.2 ,  0.2 ,  2.66,  2.66,  3.  , 47.5 , 16.95, 17.56]
```

And the result should be:

```
[[11.95, 11.95],  [2.5, null] ,  [1.2, 1.2] ,  [0.6, null] ,  [2.66, 2.66],  [2.66, 2.66],  [3., 3] , [47.5, 45.5 ], [16.95, 16.95], [17.56, 17.56]]
```

Comment: I don't think so, I want to replace the first and only the first value by a based on that criteria. Are you saying to do something like this ```despesas['recibos'].loc[np.where((despesas['despesas']==a) & (despesas['recibos']==''), 1,0)]=a``` ?

Comment: @Datanovice, this isn't numpy.where

Comment: @JoseMacedo could you show an example and your expected output?

Comment: tell me if it works: `despesas['recibos'] = despesas['despesas'].where(despesas['despesas'].isin(recibos['recibos']) & (~despesas['despesas'].duplicated()),'')`

Comment: @ansev It almost worked, but the problem is when I have 2 values on recibos, I want to 2 values of despesas to be updated as well, ofc If I have 2 of them, if I have 3 on *despesas* and only 2 on *recibos* I want to update 2

Comment: could you show an example ?

Comment: @ansev I already edited the post, do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think It is incosistent

Comment: @ansev What do you mean?

Comment: I think I might need more data, but check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that I was looking for

```
from itertools import count, filterfalse

despesas['recibos'] =''
for index, a in despesas.iterrows():
    if len(recibos.loc[recibos['recibos']==a['despesas']])>0:
        despesas.iloc[index,1]=True
        recibos.drop(recibos.loc[recibos['recibos']==a['despesas']][:1].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be works:

```
mapper = recibos['recibos'].map(despesas['despesas'].value_counts()).fillna(0)
despesas['recibos'] = recibos['recibos'].where(recibos.groupby('recibos')
                                                      .cumcount()
                                                      .lt(mapper),'null')
print(despesas)
   despesas recibos
0     11.95   11.95
1      2.50     1.2
2      1.20    null
3      0.60    null
4      2.66    2.66
5      2.66    2.66
6      3.00       3
7     47.50    47.5
8     16.95   16.95
9     17.56   17.56
```

Comment: Sorry man! Actually I had an inconsistency on the value 2.5.... I just saw it now!!!! So, where is [2.5,1.2] it should be [2.5,null], and where is [1.2, null] it should be [1.2, 1.2] I already updated the question. Sorry about that